# Magento 2 get list of the guest orders

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, orders, collection

I want to show list of the guest user in my custom module.  Which is the best way to get the list of the guest order.

How can i get list of the guest orders?

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $lastyear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 year"));

  $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id)->addAttributeToFilter('state', 'complete')->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['gteq'  => $lastyear]);
```

To get the guest orders i am getting collection of all the orders and checking  customer email address. If user with that email address doesn't exist then consider it as guest order.

Is this correct flow?  Is there any other flow to check guest orders?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get guest customer order list by below code.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,

) {
    $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
}

public function getGuestOrderCollection()
{
    $orderCollecion = $this->orderCollectionFactory
        ->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect('*');

    $orderCollecion->addAttributeToFilter('customer_is_guest', ['eq'=>1]);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($orderCollecion->getData());
    exit; 
    return $orderCollecion;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help.  what's the use of following code?  $totalGuestOrder = $this->getRequest()->getParam('total_guest_order');
    if ('all' !== $totalGuestOrder){
        $orderCollecion->getSelect()->limit((int)$totalGuestOrder);
    }

Is it possible for you to explain?

Comment: Check my updated answer, this code is not for you.

Comment: Thanks suresh but can you tell me what's the use of that code.  I am learner so it would help me.

Comment: Which code are use for curl request, in your case it was not useful. From above code you will get list of guest users order list.

Comment: Ok thanks.  If i want to print this collection then $orderCollection->getData()  will work?  or $this->_logger->debug($orderCollecion);

Comment: Yes, it will work.

Comment: Have you checked?

Comment: I am trying to log it through   $this->_logger->debug($orderCollecion);   but it gives me error. debug.log giving following error:  main.CRITICAL: Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection could not be converted to string in /opt/lampp/htdocs/m2/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 323

Comment: check my updated answer to print order data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72437/discussion-between-suresh-chikani-and-jack).

Comment: Does guest customer Id exists ? if yes how can we get through Order collection or some other way

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code to get list of guest orders:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_is_guest', ['eq'=>1]);
```